# In C#, can I check at compile-type whether a class is serializable?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, compile-time

I have a [Serializable] class in C# that has many fields, each a different class. I use serialization to save/load instances of this class but it happens often to me that I forget to add a [Serializable] attribute somewhere and only learn this at runtime. Can this be checked during compilation?

For example, this code,

```
[Serializable]
class House {
 List<Room> Rooms;
}
class Room
{
}
```

should not pass the validation because the Room class is not serializable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: You can't use reflection at compile time.

Comment: @MatthewWatson *Can this be checked during compilation?*

Comment: Oops misread that! I have removed it. :)

Comment: As mentioned in the other question, you can do it with a custom FxCop rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's nothing you can do at compile-time.

However, it's easy to add a unit test for this - you could find each serializable class within your assembly, and recursively find all fields and check that each one is serializable. Of course, a simpler approach would simply be to serialize an instance :)

A unit test isn't as good as a compile-time check, but it's better than only doing it "live".

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to determine if a type is serializable or not at compile time.  For types that implement `ISerializable` this can be done by restricting an API to take only `ISerializable`.  But this doesn't work for the types decorated with `[Serializable]` because you can't constrain an API to take types which have a specific attribute applied to them